# Javascript Date.getFullYear() behaving same as Date.getYear()

Tags: javascript, date, y2k

I'm trying to get the year using Javascript.  I instantiated a new Date().  I was able to get the month and date without issue.  The year is not working as it should.  I am using getFullYear() as all the docs and comments say to, not getYear() but, I get 117 instead of 2017.  According to everything I've read getYear() should return 117 and getFullYear() should return 2017.  In the console, if I run ' (new Date()).getFullYear() ' I get 2017.

If I declare the Task function in the console and then instantiate a new Task object, everything works properly.  The task object's year property will be 2017.

What am I doing wrong?

```js
function Task(task) {
  var d = new Date();

  this.task = task;
  this.date = d.getDate();
  this.month = d.getMonth();
  this.year = d.getFullYear()
  this.complete = false;
}

var task = new Task("task one");
['date', 'month', 'year'].forEach(function(p) {
  console.log(p + ' is ' + task[p]);
});

// date is 28
// month is 8
// year is 117
```

Comment: You set `task.year = 117` ?

Comment: I if `console.log(task.year)` I get 2017. Prior to when you overwrite the values from the function of course.

Comment: No, I was just writing what each property ends up being.  I see it's confusing, I'll edit.

Comment: Converting your code to a runnable snippet doesn't display the claimed error. Voting to close as "can't replicate".

Comment: What browser are you using? It works fine on my end

Comment: I see 2017 in the snippet above. What browser are you using where you see 117?

Comment: I'm using chrome.  I tried in Safari and got the same thing.  It works in the snippet for me also.

Comment: In the console, if I run ' (new Date()).getFullYear() ' I get 2017

Comment: Which chrome version your are using?

Comment: Version 61.0.3163.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: The snippet works here on the site.  When I copy the code and run it locally, I get 117.

Comment: It works for me even in local.

Comment: It does give 117 if you use `getYear` and 2017 for `getFullYear`. You have used `getFullYear` in your snippet, hence the result

Answer (score 0):

I was using the incorrect js file.  The file I had updated with getFullYear() is not the one that was being run.  The one that was being run was using getYear().